# Pillow can't import

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a Problem with the Pillow module.
So basically i tried the methods on this website installing it per `pip install Pillow` and also importing it per `from PIL import Image` and `import PIL` none of them worked

I would really appreciate it if someone helped
and thanks for reading. This is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import pyscreeze
from PIL import Image
lkchat = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("python.png")
print ("lkchat")
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> from PIL import Image
>   ImportError: No module named PIL

Comment: What OS are you using? What command do you use to start `Python`?

Comment: im using windows 10 and i start the script by basically debugging mode so i execute it self in python with F5

Answer (score 0):

Kitty Star i would like to suggest you that replace PIL with pillow and then install pillow if your code does not run let me know the next error.

Comment: hello thanks for youre answer the error message now is

`from pillow import Image
ImportError: No module named pillow`
and i edited: `from PIL import Image` to `from pillow import Image`
btw i have python 3.8.0